# jQuery addClass() inside bootstraps shown.bs.tab event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have two objects with svg-graphics each inside an .tab-pane from Bootstrap.
Inside these SVG's I want elements to be styled and therefore add css classes with jquery. On debugging I can see that the classes are still being added correctly to $elem.classList, but not inside the elements class-attribute in svg.

This is the code that adds the class. The only thing that I had to change where the first 5 lines, to work inside bootstrap Panel.

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var whichObj = e.target.href.slice(-5);
    var doc = $(".raumplan",whichObj)[0];
    var svg = doc.contentDocument.documentElement;

    var refs = new XMLHttpRequest();
    refs.open("GET", "/RaumRefs", true);
    refs.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (refs.readyState === 4 && refs.status === 200) {
            raumReferat = JSON.parse(refs.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < raumReferat.length; i++) {
                var id = raumReferat[i].raum.replace(/\./g,'\\.');
                if (id != "") {
                    var elem = $("#" + id, svg);

                    elem.addClass("ref" + raumReferat[i].referat+" buero");
                    if (raumReferat[i].besetzt == true) {
                        elem.addClass("besetzt");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    refs.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(refs.statusText);
    }
    refs.send(null);
}
```

It is correctly selecting the elem by id from the correct svg and add the correct classes. But why has it no effect on the like without panels?

Additional information:
This only happens in chrome, ie and firefox are working, like they should.

Comment: As IDs are unique, so you don't have to use context in the selector.

Comment: @Jai: I thought so before but I need to use context, because else js didn't find the id inside the embedded svg as it is an own document